# Define Instance of Template class

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to define the implementation of a template class at compile time to be then used at run time?

Here is my class

```
template <typename T>
class CDetectError
{
public:
    CDetectError();
    CDetectError(T errorStart, T notAvailableStart)
    {
       m_Error = errorStart;
       m_NotAvailable = notAvailableStart;
    }

virtual ~CDetectError();

T Error() const {return m_Error;}
T NotAvailable() const {return m_NotAvailable;}

private:
    T m_Error;
    T m_NotAvailable;
};
```

What i would like then is that if I define an instance of that class at compile time as

`CDetectError<unsigned char>(0xFE, 0xFF);`

Then anytime `CDetectError<unsigned char>::Error()` is used it returns 0xFE.

Comment: What about static data members or static local variables?

Comment: In what way are you describing?

Comment: Well if you want to set some values when *instantiatiating the class* = *create an object of that class* `CDetectError<unsigned char>`, and at run-time want all objects of that class to return `0xFE` for `Error()`, then you can just introduce a static data member, set that when instantiating the class, and make `Error()` a static member function.

Comment: I am still not sure i see where you are heading. How do i 'just introduce' a static member?

Comment: After re- and re-reading your question, I think I don't quite understand what you want to do. Do you want to write `CDetectError<unsigned char> x(0xFE, 0xFF);` and then `x.Error()` shall be a *constant expression* (= compile-time constant)? Or do you want to write `CDetectError<unsigned char> x(0xFE, 0xFF);` just once anywhere in your program and then, for all objects of the type `CDetectError<unsigned char>` (e.g. `CDetectError<unsigned char> y;`) the function `Error()` always returns `0xFE` (e.g. `y.Error() == 0xFE`)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to achieve your second scenario. If i create `x` and `y` instantiated as `CDetectError<unsigned char>` I want `Error()` to return 0xFE for all cases of `unsigned char`

Comment: Then why don't you make `m_Error` a static data member?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use template specialization as follows:

```
template<class T>
struct ErrorStart;

template<>
struct ErrorStart<unsigned char> {
    static const unsigned char Error = 0xFE;
};
```

Then you can say `ErrorStart<unsigned int>::Error` and always get the same result.
You can also use that `ErrorStart` struct within the definition of `CDetectError` to reuse code.